# c# how to correctly format an ffmpeg user input stream?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, ffmpeg

So I'm writing a c# application which allows a user to scale a video in pixels to a custom dimension. I am strugeling to get the user input from a textbox for the mpeg psi arguments:

Here is the code:

```
 var localStoragePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), name);
                            var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(localStoragePath);
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
                            File.WriteAllBytes(localStoragePath, bytes);
                            Progress.Text = ($"File copy successful: {File.Exists(localStoragePath)}");
                            var readBack = File.ReadAllBytes(localStoragePath);
                            Progress.Text = ($"Read file Back: {readBack.Length}, {localStoragePath}");
                            var resizedFolderPath = @"C:\upscaledvideohere";
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(resizedFolderPath);
                            var resizedFiePath = Path.Combine(resizedFolderPath, Path.GetFileName(localStoragePath));

                            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                            psi.FileName = @"C:\ffmpeg-2020-12-27-git-bff6fbead8-full_build\bin\ffmpeg.exe";
                            psi.Arguments = $"-i \"{localStoragePath}\" -vf scale=" + pixelsheight.Text  "\"{resizedFiePath}\"";
                            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
                            psi.RedirectStandardError = false;
                            psi.UseShellExecute = true;
                            Progress.Text = ($"Args: {psi.Arguments}");
```

For

```
 psi.Arguments = $"-i \"{localStoragePath}\" -vf scale=" + pixelsheight.Text  "\"{resizedFiePath}\""
```

What would be the correct way to input the text for what the user typedin the pixelsheight text box?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Did I not already answer this?

Comment: No, thank you. This is the first comment on here.

Comment: You missed '+' and '$'. Should be `$"-i \"{localStoragePath}\" -vf scale=" + pixelsheight.Text + $" \"{resizedFiePath}\""`

Comment: *This the first comment on here* - I was referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65502499/trouble-using-ffmpeg-in-c-sharp-how-to-correctly-format-string-to-upscale-videos)

Comment: @KyleWang actually the whole thing should be interpolated, as it was in the question I already answered

Answer (score 0):

Your previous question had it more correct. You're mixing concat and interpolation when it would be simpler to just interpolate

```
$"-i \"{localStoragePath}\" -vf scale=-1:{pixelsheight.Text} \"{resizedFiePath}\""
```

I'd also make the pixelsHeight a NumericUpDown rather than a text, to prevent the headache of having to ensure number input on a textbox

---

Stop copying massive movie files by reading them all into a byte array in memory, copying it into another byte array, and then reading the file into another that you never use, and then writing to disk. It will cost 1.5gb of memory to run ffmpeg on a 500mb movie. Use System.IO.File.Copy and it won't use any memory